# Eclipse Java package diagram from source code

Tags: java, maven, package, hierarchy, diagram

Are there any way of generating a package diagram from the java source code of an eclipse project?

My project is a maven multi-module, where distinct modules "share" packages, ie, there can be a class in a module that is in the same java package of a class that belongs to another module.

I would want to show the packages and the relationships between them , no matter the modules where packages belong to.

Also, are there any tool to show the package hierarchy tree? (no matter the maven modules), similar to "tree" command in linux, that show the directory tree of the file system.

Thank you.